# Music Player in Notification Bar Architecture

Tags: java, android, kotlin

So I'm creating an app with MVVM, which is a Music Player, managed by Notification Bar.
The only action I want to use Activity for is to start the player.

Right now all the logic is in the activity, and the app works perfectly fine this way. But I want to move the logic someplace else. When I relocate all the logic to a regular class, though, I can't access the Viewmodel. What would be the right way to separate player instantiation from its management? Fragment? Service? Something else?

Thanks in advance. Any ideas will be very appreciated.

[notification bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkE0P.png)

Comment: Use "Service" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it turns out that the best way to manage player and its inner state in a started bound service.
It should be **started** so it won't stop when an activity goes down, and it should be **bound** in case you want to connect notification to activity.